# Issue in installing VS code extensions

Tags: vscode-extensions, extension-methods

I am not able to install any extension in VS code when I click on install its just keep on installing forever but never installing.

just installed vs code
Tried isntalling C++ intellisense and other extensions
It keep on loading and after sometime it stops installing and says "Error while installing'C/C++' extension. Please check the log for more details. "Try Downloading Manually".

Here are the logs :
2023-07-14 17:28:21.653 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 52ms
2023-07-14 17:29:40.905 [error] Download: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
at $t.download (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:86:135269)
at async G.y (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:19783)
at async G.h (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:17877)
2023-07-14 17:29:40.982 [error] net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED: Download: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
at $t.download (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:86:135269)
at async G.y (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:19783)
at async G.h (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:17877)
2023-07-14 17:33:39.958 [error] Download: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
at $t.download (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:86:135269)
at async G.y (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:19783)
at async G.h (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:17877)
2023-07-14 17:33:40.015 [error] net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED: Download: net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
at $t.download (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:86:135269)
at async G.y (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:19783)
at async G.h (c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:87:17877)

I have tried using google's public IPv4 and IPv6 DNS address.

When I click on "try Downloading Manually" is opens the browser and says:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Talk to your network administrators. This isn't something anyone here can help with.

Comment: This problem is solved now. I also raised a GitHub query and found out upgrading to the new version solved the problem.